# Is it possible to make alert dialog dissapear after page navigation?

Tags: flutter, dart

The "OK" button on my alert dialog navigates to a new page. But when I go back to the previous page, the alert is still there. Is there any way for the alert to disappear after I navigate to the new page?

```
// Alert Dialog
Future<void> _handlePhoto(BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: Text('Please Position Crosshair'),
        content: const Text(
            'Before detecting cancer, ensure your focus area is centered.'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                '/camerapage',
                arguments: cameras,
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before pushing the new page, you need to pop the dialog like this. So when you come back it is not there.

```
onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                '/camerapage',
                arguments: cameras,
              );
            }
```